# What key does the symbol "⇧" represent?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

For instance, the [Sublime Text Unofficial Docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html) say that on Linux, I can use this key sequence...

> Alt + ⇧ + Up

... to do column selection. I have no idea what this key is if it is not "Up".

Someone out there just knows the answer to this question.

Comment: I think Sublime Text was originally for the Mac, so they're using Apple's notation.

Comment: It would seem you're not alone...

Comment: Seriously! 23 upvotes on the question as of this writing. I guess it's one of those obvious questions that still needs to be answered.

Comment: It means You need to press Alt, look **up** towards the ceiling, then press up :)

Comment: Press Alt + Up. P.S. Look out for that falling anvil!

Comment: @Bepetersn Obvious to people who are in their 30s and up at the time of this post.  This falls into a category of historical knowledge that people are losing.  When is the last time you even saw a typewriter?  Or remembered the shift key has an up arrow on it?  I saw a video of a person showing grade school kids old technology.  They thought a typewriter was an old laptop and asked where it plugged in and where the screen was.  I want those kids to get off my lawn.

Comment: @Moses Nah, it means "press Alt while in your house, then press up"

Comment: @Keltari I want a lawn

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It means press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>

Check your keyboard's <kbd>Shift</kbd> for ⇧ printed on the key.  Not all have them, though.

This originated in typewriters, where the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key actually raised the letter fan assembly.

Comment: Lol, ok, I'm an idiot.

Comment: can someone edit this?  I dont know how to make an up arrow. :P

Comment: Copy-paste. 

The only reason I didn't think it was shift was because they use that word elsewhere, so I assumed it had to mean something else.

Comment: @Keltari Given the confusion caused by having up arrows in the first place, it might be a good idea to leave this message free of up arrows. :P

Comment: To add to the confusion, Caps Lock is often denoted as ⇩ ([example](http://images.speedlink.com/prodpics/_spl/SL-6410-SBK/large/sl-6410-sbk_rgb_001.jpg)).

Comment: Hehe, it would be even funnier to have the sequence written as Alt+⇧+↑

Comment: @primo That's a weird keyboard. It also has ↑ and ↓ for page up and page down, respectively. Personally I've seen more keyboards that use ⇪ for caps lock.

Comment: @MrLister ⇪ does seem more common, from a quick google image search. FWIW, the model I linked is the one I've been using for the past 8 years.

Comment: The historical reason for shift to be indicated by an arrow is the design of old typewriters. The levers would have [two letters on each](http://cdn4.explainthatstuff.com/typewriter-type-hammers.jpg), and the shift button would *literally* shift them so the capital letter would hit instead of lowercase. I've never seen Caps Lock as a down arrow, but considering once upon a time it *literally* locked the shift button down, it makes a little sense.

Comment: @primo It also uses that exact same symbol for the scroll lock it seems.

Comment: I actually remember seeing the question's `⇧` on CapsLock, not the one with the bar mentioned by @MrLister (although my current laptop's CapsLock has no icon)

Comment: @primo - is this (⇩ for caps) a German thing (the keyboard is German by the look of things) - I've never seen ⇩ for caps, it's normally `A`, `[A]` or ⇪ in the UK.